# How does "C" know about the history of the house?

Tags: plot-explanation, a-ghost-story

In the movie *[A Ghost Story](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6265828/)*, C (played by Casey Affleck) doesn't want to move out of the house and the reason he says is that there is a history attached to that house. How does he know this?

And what does the ghost in the neighborhood mean when it says it can't remember what she is waiting for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He don't know the history.

This is an expression "have a history attached to it". It means that if something is old it been around long enough it gathered some events when it was a part of them. Just like "if only those wall could talk, I bet they could tell us some stories".

For the second part this is kind of plot explanation. The ghost have been around for so long it forget why it stick around. M tries to watch C. But after C death who he will be watching? And then he will forget. Unable to move forward or backward (as backward mean being alive again) it will be stuck in mortal plane.